# I want to select date and time 8 days and 8 hours ahead in datepicker and timepicker in CYPRESS

Tags: javascript, cypress, flatpickr

I want to select a date which 8 days ahead of today in cypress . I have tried it with the following code but can we use a numeric value in ".nextuntil()" to iterate to 8th element from current one ?

```
cy.get('.dayContainer > .today').nextUntil().click()
```

I have tried code from @steve but getting following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYQFX.png)

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the date picker ? Are you using this - https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/

Comment: Hi , Yes we are using flatpickr.

Comment: @AlapanDas can you please help me on this ?

Comment: This question has already been asnwered by Steve Zodiac. You can check the attached link from above.

Comment: @AlapanDas I have used the code but getting following error


Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay flatpickr-disabled" aria-label="Juli 26, 2021">26</span>

This element <span.flatpickr-day.prevMonthDay.flatpickr-disabled> is not visible because its parent <div.flatpickr-calendar.animate> has CSS property: display: none

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking

Comment: I fixed a bug in the previous answer, please see if that helps you.